# Isolating and customizing first image in Wordpress post

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

I have a Wordpress site which uses a feature image on the posts which link to a page with the post's content (images, content, etc)

I separate out the images from the content with

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
    for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
    echo $images[1][$i];
    }
?>
```

I want to target the first image of each individual post (it is not the featured image) I want to put

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

overtop the first image, to make it act as a header for the post, then I can have the other images and text underneath. not sure how to accomplish this

EDIT - clarification

My index.php shows the featured image of each post in a 'thumbnail gallery' style. each picture links to content-single.php where the content and images are displayed for that post (the featured image is NOT on this page). content-single.php is where i pull out the text and the images

I want to be able to put a title overlapping the first image of the post (NOT the featured image on index.php) because I want the first image of the content to act as a header for each single post page

Comment: Your image is in the content of the post? If it is really a featured image you can easily display it whatever you want in the template - so between `the_title` and `the_content`.

Comment: Apply the first image as a background to the h1, that would be my choice.

Comment: @vard the OP says *not featured image*

Comment: @Aaron Got confused by the first sentence of the question. Though OP should give some context here, it's unclear what he's asking. Why can't he call `the_title()` before his image loop, is he out of the loop?

Comment: @vard very good point

Comment: added an edit to my question to hopefully explain it better

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This.

```
    $content = apply_filters ("the_content", $post->post_content);

    preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$content, $result);

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($result);
```

i hope this is useful for you.!

Comment: will that just display the first photo?

Comment: `print_r($result);` it Display array of all image.for Frist Image `$result[0][0];`

Comment: oh ok, i'll have to figure out how to implement it. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
  preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$get_the_content(), $result);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
```

For Frist Image Try this `$result[0][0]`.

It Get All Images.

Comment: will that still post all the images similar to how I have it now?