# Putting header on first image of post

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and I want to put a header over-top the first image in a list/stack of images. I am using the following code to pull the images out of the text of the post content.

HTML

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
    for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
        echo $images[1][$i];
    }
?>
```

This puts all the images in my post, One on top of the other (each pic is set to 100% width of screen and a specific height). I want to target the FIRST image so I can put

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ? ></h1 >
```

over-top of it. Not sure how to accomplish this

Comment: Is this not [a duplicate of your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246621/isolating-and-customizing-first-image-in-wordpress-post) ?

Comment: yes, the answers provided did not work, and no new suggestions were offered. I also tried rewording it better this time and got a working response

Comment: Good for you that you got a response this time, but you should not do duplicates of your own questions. Try next time to edit your orignal question to reword it - the edit will send the question back to the top of the newest questions. So no need to create duplicates.

Comment: Though why did you marked as resolved the previous question? Which answer is the right solution to your problem, this one from Mike or the one you marked on the other question?

Comment: Did not know editing question would do that. The code/answer from the other was not a complete answer. I tried using it but did not achieve the desired results. I tried asking again in a simpler way and got a code which works perfectly. Both answers are right, but the one from this works more specifically to my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$i` to determine if you are looping on the first index or not.

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
    for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            // only printed when looping on 1st image with a wrapped <div> element
            echo sprintf('<div><h1>%s</h1>%s</div>', get_the_title(), $images[1][$i]);
            continue;
        }

        echo $images[1][$i];
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorta new to advanced coding, so this will put the <h1> over top the first image and then have the other images underneath?

Comment: Yes exactly, you will first have your <h1>, then the images. You should use CSS to put the title on top of the image.

Comment: That's my concern, I need code to at least have the image and the header in the same div, so I can use absolute positioning and keep it within the image

Comment: I've updated the code where title and image (only for 1st loop) is wrapped in a `<div>` element.

Comment: awesome thank you, I should be able to work with this nicely done